# jQuery EasyUI: confirmation on close window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

I am using the jQuery EasyUI framework. I want a confirmation message on close window like "Are you sure you want to close the window?". If the answer is true then close else do not close window.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is is not directly providing by Easy-UI
if you want then you need to disable close button of window Like

```
.panel-tool-close
    {
        display:none !important;
    }
```

and add your custom tool bar
Like this in document.ready function

```
jQuery('#divSeguimientos').window({  
        collapsible:false,  
        minimizable:false,  
        maximizable:false,  
        tools:[{  
            iconCls:'icon-cancel',  
            handler:function(){  
                if(confirm('Are you sure to close the window?'))
                    {
                        closeDivSeguimientos();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

            }  
        }]  
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$.messager.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure to exit this system?', function(r){
    if (r){
        // exit action;
    }
});
```

see [Messanger API](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/messager.php)

Comment: how can i set it on close event of window?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('#windowid').window({
onBeforeClose: function(){
    $.messager.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure to exit this system?', function(r)
            {
             if (r){
                  return true;
              }
             else{return false;}
            });                    
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not provided by easy ui.
So you have to hide or set css display property of close button set none.

also set close button class.

```
.panel-tool-close
    {
        display:none !important;
    }
```

please try this.

```
tools:[{  
            iconCls:'icon-cancel',  
            handler:function(){  
                if(confirm('Are you sure to close?'))
                    {
                        closeDiv();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

            }  
        }]
```